# how can I understand about the container 'to be as small as possible'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the Container.class is describe as 'to be as small as possible',but I have tried Container without child,it full of the screen,so how can I understand as small as possible

````
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MappState createState() {
    return MappState();
  }

}


class MappState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'myApp',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(color: Colors.red,),
      ),
    );
  }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The docs are [very clear about this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html):

> Containers with no children try to be **as big as possible** unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be **as small as possible**. Containers with children size themselves to their children. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this.

An unbounded constraint is either width or height set to `double.infinity`.

No child -> 'As **big** as possible'

No child unbounded -> 'As **small** as possible'

I recommend you to see [this article](https://medium.com/@realank/dive-into-flutter-container-19e5bdfd56fc), it has some code examples with images, illustrating these behaviors of constraints.